# How do I solve this error from my code KeyError Date Adj Close not found in axis

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

Running the code below and it is giving me an error that I have outlined bellow:

```
   #import libraries:
    import numpy as np
    import streamlit as st
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas_datareader as data
    from keras.models import load_model

    start = '2010-01-01'
    end = '2021-08-20'

    df = data.DataReader('CENTUM.NS', 'yahoo', start, end)
    df.head()

    df.tail()

    df = df.reset_index()
    df.head()

    df=df.drop(['Date','Adj Close'],axis = 1)
    df.head()
```

The error I am getting:

> KeyError: "['Date' 'Adj Close'] not found in axis"

Comment: Since the date is an index, if you remove it and then delete the column, no error will occur. `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the column, it would be something different than Adj Close, Like close or something.Its a name error,nothing else.